# Moving files from SFTP to WindowsShare via SMB in WSO2

Tags: wso2, sftp, wso2-esb, smb, wso2-integration-studio

I am trying to move all xml files from SFTP to Windows Share using SMB protocol.
Below is the proxy service I've tried:

```
<proxy name="WindowsShare" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="STATUS" value="Reading File Data"/>
                <property name="XML data from file" expression="$body/*"/>
            </log>
            <property expression="get-property('transport','FILE_NAME')" name="filename" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('transport','FILE_NAME')" name="filename"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">sftp://[username]:[password]@[hostname]:22/[filePath]?sftpPathFromRoot=true&amp;transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ResolveHostsDynamically">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">sftp://[username]:[password]@[hostname]:22/[filePath]?sftpPathFromRoot=true&amp;transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">smb://[username]:[password]@[hostname]/[filePath]</parameter>
</proxy>
```

I am able to get the xml content logs, but it gives an error while moving to windows share.
It keeps giving error - "jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" though the jcifs jar is already there. I'm able to connect to the windowsShare server using same credentials via smb in java. But it doesn't work here. I'm using micro-integrator-4.0.0.

Comment: Do you have special characters in the username or password?

Comment: Yes, But I've encoded all the special characters to Hex. Ex: for = I've given %3D

Comment: How would we encode characters like >? should that also be hex or &gt; since thats how wso2 reads.